# iOS 7 UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I discover that in a iOS7 `UITableView` (in plain and in grouped style) is the same set the separator style in `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched` or `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`. The table view appears without separator. It's a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not a bug, it is just another victim of the iOS7 flatten UI, just like UIButtons have no borders, and don't forget that etched line does't fit with flat UI.